# How to set Message Breakpoints on button in ollyDbg 2.01?

Tags: ollydbg

In OllyDbg 110 there is a point: "Message breakpoint on ClassProc".
[image: OllyDbg 110]

At OllyDbg 2.01 I can not find it:

[image: OllyDbg 2.01]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use conditional log breakpoint and set multiple conditions
```

[image]